# Easy way to re-order asp:GridView?

Tags: html, asp.net

I was wondering if there was a built in way to re-organize the elements of a gridview, so that the user can for instance sort them by an ID number or date. Preferably in the behind code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GridView's [Sort method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort.aspx).